# Remove apostrophe from arraylist

Tags: python, replace, special-characters

I have some list of array, separated with ';'

```
O;4;State[1', '25', '3];CPUA.DB1610.274,X5;RW
V;5;LostClClamp;CPUA.DB1610.276,X3;RW
O;4;State[1', '26', '1];CPUA.DB1610.276,X5;RW
```

for example: `result[0][2:3] == State[1', '25', '3]`
And I want to remove apostrophe character:

```
for n in range(len(result)):
    if "'" in result[n][2:3]:
        result[n][2:3].replace("'", "")
```

But this code not work like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming result is the list containing the strings, ie. `result="O;4;State[1', '25', '3];CPUA.DB1610.274,X5;RW".split(';')`

```
for i, x in enumerate(result):
    result[i] = result.replace("'","")
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` method does not modify the string, it just returns a copy, thus you need to type:

```
result[n][2:3] = result[n][2:3].replace("'", "")
```

Comment: `for n in range(len(result)):`

            `if "'" in result[n][2:3]:`

                `result[n][2:3] = result[n][2:3].replace("'", "")`

            `print(result[n][2:3])`


And still I have apostrophe: `Statistics[1', '54', '2]`